# Simple centralized system to store and share information at an office

Tags: database, excel

I work at an office with some colleagues generating and consuming structured data which can be normally stored in a database. For instance:
- data from several countries: capital, population, currency, ...
- forecasts of the evolution of the population in each country: each year we generate one different time series

We store these data in dozens of Excel files (which is the last version?, where are they stored?, are they in a shared directory?), and we produce lots of document from these data (power point files, other Excel files to make calculations, ...).

I know how to install a mySQL server on Linux, and I could build a web-app to generate and store data, and I could build an API to consume the data. But I wondered if there was any other smarter solution to implement a simple centralized system to store and share information at an office.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to implement a cloud service here instead of working things from scratch - just to save the time and effort. Here are two cloud service solutions with some pros and cons of their features. If anything strikes to be useful, I would recommend looking deeper into them.

**Cloud Service 1**

If storing and sharing of files is the key point here, using an online storage system like [box.com](https://www.box.com) would be a good solution. I personally like box.com better than Dropbox since it seems to have better Admin capabilities when working in teams (I may just be baiased here).

Pros:

- there are version histories for uploaded files, and files can be locked so they cannot be downloaded
- there are access stats (logs) for each file, so you know when someone viewed or downloaded files
- there's an area for Box users to leave comments for each file that is uploaded
- Excel/Word/Powerpoint files can be previewed in the browser before
  downloading them (and other files as well - personally found that
  preview of vector files being very useful)
- directories and files are immediately accessable via mobile after uploading
- shared links can be generated for each file or directory for users without Box accounts to view and download

Cons:

- Users will need a Box account to upload files (even for the shared links)
- Users may be more used to the Dropbox UI and may find Box to be have a different UX than expected (althoug the UI is not hard to master at all)

**Cloud Service 2**

If finding an SQL alternative is the key point here, using an online database platform such as [kintone](https://www.kintone.com/) would be a good solution. kintone allows you to build customizable online tables (called "Apps" in kintone) using drag and drop.

Pros:

- live graphs can be generated on kintone from the stored data
- database tables can be created and updated really easily with just the GUI
- you can define table columns (or "Fields") to store attachment files
- each row (or "Record") has an area for users to leave comments
- each Record has a history feature, so you know who edited what contents and when. Nothing is saved locally on your computer, so the latest data is always online (no conflicts occur)
- kintone also has internal forums (or "Spaces") that can be used as an alternative for internal emails.
- Apps and Spaces are instantly accessable via mobile
- kintone has [open REST APIs and JavaScript customization](https://developer.kintone.io) capabilities for any further UI changes or connecting with other sources

Cons:

- users need a kintone account to view data or to add data into apps, although there are 3rd party solutions (at a reasonable price) that allow you to do that
- it may not be as intuitive as storing data in excel spreadsheets (but that's mainly because everyone's used to excel)

Further questions about cloud services may belong better in the Software Recommendations Community https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

I'm personally good with the kintone APIs, so if you have any further questions related to API (capabilities, limits, possibilities etc), please go ahead to post them here in stackoverflow